# In the context of a review of an academic paper, what does "technical accuracy" mean?

Tags: peer-review, terminology

I have been asked to review an academic conference paper for a computer-science conference. One of the elements, the review must contain is a review of “technical accuracy.* What does this mean exactly? Is it the ability of the author to use the English language? Or is it supposed to be a review of their ability in the particular subject matter? Or something else?

Answer (score 14):

Technical accuracy is that the approach taken in the paper and the results presented correct and are precisely and correctly presented.

It is only indirectly related to language, in that if the language is poor then communicating technical content is difficult.

I don't know how you can review the authors' ability from a paper. You can only review what is in the paper.

Comment: Well, not just correctly presented: also correct, I would think.  My interpretation of "technical accuracy" is that the technical stuff in the paper is actually correct.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: That too. Now fixed.

Comment: Also check (especially for ESL authors) that there are no ambiguities in the text, and that poorly worded sentences mean what they should mean. I'm not sure that's part of the technical accuracy section per se, but language that affects the technical accuracy needs to be fixed.